# error "command not found" when run "android update project -p" in cygwin

Tags: java, android-ndk, cygwin

I got a trouble. When I create and build a project java native, I got an error:

```
-bash: android: command not found when run "android update project -p" in cygwin.
```

I use windows 7,  and I set environment variables : `ANDROID_HOME` and `PATH.`
I searched on this site but with them I cannot fix it.
Please help me

Answer (score 1):

Try this

Go to android tools directory and type
**./android update project -p**

Answer (score 0):

`command not found` typically indicates that your `PATH` variable is not set correctly.
In windows

```
set PATH = %PATH%;C:\devtools\adt-bundle-windows-x86_64\adt-bundle-windows-x86_64\sdk\tools;
```

Comment: Echo your PATH and check to see if it's contains the android bin folder

Comment: I do not understand your mind Sajan Chandran, I set PATH = %PATH%;C:\Development\sdk\tools;C:\Development\android-ndk-r9 but it not work. Please help me